# NetBeans design view size - zooming in/out

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins, designview

Quick question - is it possible to zoom in / out the Design view in NetBeans?

I am making an app in Java that has a fixed frame size (my laptop's fullscreen) and I can't see the whole frame in the design view what is a bit inconvenient. I found information that is possible to zoom in/out the code (the source view) but can't find anything on the design view and cannot find such a functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is **no such thing developed** to Zoom in/out Design View in Netbeans. As you mentioned, yes, there is a plugin to resize the Source Code window ([here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53555/editor-zoom)). All we can do is just hope for NetBeans to provide this feature to all its users in its next update.

Answer (score 1):

Try the combination of Alt + mouse wheel ;-)