# how to zoom in/out view design on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, view, zooming, frame

I'm making an application on NetBeans and I can't see the whole frame in design view. so is it possible to use zoom in / out on NetBeans? and I can't find the button or what makes zoom in / out work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NetBeans design view size - zooming in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221040/netbeans-design-view-size-zooming-in-out)

Answer (score 0):

Alt + mouse scroll will allow you to zoom In/Out the text written in the editor.
Hope I resolve your query.